# Madness and Conspiracy Theorist

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

Strixhaven introduces [Conspiracy Theorist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Conspiracy%20Theorist), with the triggered ability:

> Whenever you discard one or more nonland cards, you may exile one of them from your graveyard. If you do, you may cast it this turn.

Madness is a keyword ability that let's me cast cards that were discarded for an alternative cost.

Is the following possible for a non-permanent card with madness, assuming timing supports?

- Discard card with madness
- Exile card, and cast it for the madness cost. It goes to the graveyard on resolution.
- cast card with Conspiracy Theorist ability.

Answer (score 6):

No, I cannot do this.

A card discarded with madness is discarded, but is sent to exile instead of the graveyard. Rule 702.35a.

The complication is the act of casting it from exile for its madness cost. On moving it from the exile zone to the stack, the spell becomes a new object. Rule 400.7

When it resolves, and is put in the graveyard, the triggered ability of Conspiracy Theorist would not be able to find the card that was discarded.

If the card was not cast for its madness cost, it would remain the same object as it passed through exile, and could be cast from the graveyard. Rule 400.7i

Comment: A clarification on the last point: an object always becomes a different object when it moves to a different zone. Rule 400.7i causes the object to be tracked through the zone change in this situation, so that effects that are watching the discard can find it, but it's not the same object.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that.

Once you cast a spell using the Madness ability, it is no longer getting discarded. Instead, it is a spell on the stack. Once that spell resolves, it does go to the graveyard as usual, but this is a completely separate event from the card getting discarded.